# Saving loaded <iframes> and <images> to a file for subsequent use

Tags: javascript, jquery, animation, dom, iframe

I have a "div" into which are loaded a series of "iframe"s.

These are loaded sequentially and I use a onload handler to ensure that the next "iframe" is loaded only when the previous one has finished loading. 
This is to avoid overloading my browser and also the supplying src server.

Once all "iframe"s are loaded (or as each one completes loading - which I can obviously detect), I want to save the entire content of the "iframe" to a file in my hosting filespace.

This is because they take some time to load, and are used as the basis of an animation (by rotating visibility of each "iframe" once all are loaded), which I want to re-run fairly often.

I know the src urls of each "iframe" (as I use them to construct the "iframe" tags), and in order to rerun the same animation, I am trying to avoid having to load each of them from the src SaaS server when I want to re-run the animation.

Once each "iframe" has loaded, the embedded page is essentially static (but does have some interactive components - eg: tooltips), so if I could somehow cache the 'loaded' page in a file, I can re-run the animation, loading the essentially static content from each file on my host, rather than have to load each "iframe" from its src again, which takes around 10 seconds for each "iframe" (it's a very busy SaaS server and notorious for slow performance!).

As I am dealing with +/- 100 "iframe"s being able to achieve this would be very helpful!

I also load static images in the same way, but I think these are easier to handle (essentially the static images are .png's from the same server - but they are only images and not interactive in any way - eg: no tooltips etc)

In summary, I need to save the fully rendered content of the iframe once loaded in a file so that I can use it again! This may not be possible!

Any ideas anyone?